Смена описания профиля telegram с помощью telethon
Мне нужно менять описание(Bio) своего профиля через скрипт python, который использует библиотеку Telethon. Но я не могу найти такого метода в библиотеки. Даже текущую биографию не могу вывести. Как можно и через что можно реализовать смену описания?
